# Taking an infinite product of rings and modding out by ideal containing elements with finitely many nonzero entries

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let rings be **commutative but not necessarily unital**.

Let $p(i)$ denote the $i$ th prime.

Let $\mathbb{Z}_n$ denote $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$, which is a ring.

I can think of two reasonable "infinite products" $\prod_{x \in \mathbb{N}} \mathbb{Z}_{p(i)}$.

The more obvious one is $R_1 = \mathbb{Z}_{p(1)} \times \mathbb{Z}_{p(2)} \times \cdots$ , this ring is unital since $(1, 1, 1, \cdots)$ is a multiplicative identity.

The other infinite product is $R_2 \subset R_1$, consisting of precisely the elements of $R_1$ where finitely many entries are nonzero.

The multiplicative identity of $R_1$ is ruled out, but $R_2$ is still multiplicatively closed.

In fact, $R_2$ is an ideal of $R_1$.

$R_2/R_1$ is a really weird animal. It certainly has a copy of the integers inside of it, because $k \cdot (1, 1, 1, \cdots)$ will remain distinct at infinitely many places for all integers $k$.

We can also make various "impossible" integers such as $(0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0 \cdots)$, a totally nonexistent integer that's divisible by every other prime.

My question is twofold:

1. What do you call the kind of infinite product used to obtain $R_2$?
2. What ring is $R_1/R_2$?

Comment: It's not standard terminology, but I like to call things like $R_1/R_2$ sets (or rings, or whatever) of "tails".

Answer (score 1):

1. As a "product of rings" I think this is informally thought of as "the direct sum of rings"; however, it is important to know that it is not the [coproduct in the category of rings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category_of_rings#Limits_and_colimits) like it is in the category of $R$ modules over a ring $R$. Perhaps instead you should think of each $R_i$ as a right $R$ module (where $R=\prod R_i$) and then $\oplus R_i$ is the ($R$-module) coproduct of ideals, and it just happens that since $\oplus R_i$ is a subset of $R$, you get a ring product on $\oplus R_i$ as a byproduct (no pun intended.)
2. I've never heard of a name for the quotient ring $R_1/R_2$.  You could think of it as the ring whose elements are classes of elements which are "equal almost everywhere."  One interesting property the quotient has, though, is that the right and left socles are always zero.

Comment: Here's hoping I didn't say anything majorly wrong category-wise.  I know little of the properties of the colimits in the category of rings, and less of the category of rings without identity.